# Entity query criteria with static instance members

Tags: c#, entity-framework, criteria

I'm trying to create an audit-trail like order state history table. This way, Orders could have many OrderStates, and a single State which points to the most recent history item. So far so good when saving an updating. The problems arise when I try to query as if I was using an enum:

```
public class OrderState
{
    public static OrderState Placed = new OrderState("Placed", 1, 1);
    public static OrderState Accepted = new OrderState("Accepted", 10, 2);
    public static OrderState Cancelled = new OrderState("Cancelled", 20, 3);
    public static OrderState Completed = new OrderState("Completed", 30, 4);

    protected OrderState()
    {
    }

    public OrderState(string name, int order, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Order = order;
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public int Order { get; protected set; }



    public static bool operator == (OrderState state1, OrderState state2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(state1, null))
        {
            return ReferenceEquals(state2, null);
        }
        return state1.Equals(state2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(OrderState state1, OrderState state2)
    {
        return !(state1 == state2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj is OrderState))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((OrderState)obj);
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(OrderState other)
    {
        return other.Id.Equals(Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((Id.GetHashCode())*397) ^ Order;
        }
    }


}
```

Order class

```
public class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        Progress(OrderState.Placed);
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderState State
    {
        get { return States.OrderByDescending(x => x.State.Order).FirstOrDefault()?.State; }
    }

    public void Progress(OrderState state)
    {
        if (States.All(x => x.State != state))
        {
            States.Add(new OrderStateHistory()
            {
                Order = this,
                State = state
            });
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderStateHistory> States { get; set; } = new List<OrderStateHistory>();
}
```

In my code, things like these work fine:
`order.Progress(OrderState.Accepted);`, `if (order.State == OrderState.Accepted)`

However, what I'd like to get to is `Where(x => x.State.Equals(OrderState.Accepted))` or `Where(x => x.State == OrderState.Accepted)`

Unfortunately, either of the criterias will yield an 'The specified type member 'State' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.' error.

I know I have been able to do this with NHibernate. Can I even do this with EF?

Answer (score 0):

> Since EF needs to translate your LINQ statements to SQL statements,
>   you can't do this. If you have complex comparison logic in your
>   `overridden Equals()` method you will have to duplicate that in the
>   LINQ statement.

```
public IQueryable<Foo> FoosEqualTo(IQueryable<Foo> allFoos, Foo target) {
return from foo in allFoos
       where foo.Id == target.Id // or other comparison logic...
       select foo;
}

public Foo getFoo(Foo target) {
    return FoosEqualTo(DC.foos, target).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I can only assume that the FirstOrDefault() in my get is messing it up... it may be that I can't go NH way after all, and might have to attach an explicit get-private-set property for storing the current state...

Comment: Could u try without the 'x.state.equal' object comparison and pls let me know the result.

Comment: The problem lies within the fact that I do NOT want to put concerns that can be abstracted out into my queries! EF seems to have trouble parsing methods into expressions! What I don't want to do:

.where(x => x.State.Id == OrderState.Accepted.Id)

What I want to do:

.where(x => x.isInState(OrderState.Accepted));

I'm trying to place all my concerns into relevant places. There are other issues similar to this in the project, and those queries would go way bigger.